# Android unfourtunately project has stopped error

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I'm creating android app in Eclipse ADT Bundle.When clicked button app connecting web service and getting location values in app.I started app in emulator, while i'm receiving "unfourtunately project name has stopped" warning. I'm checking out logcat.But I didn't solve problem. I'm sharing down logcat errors. Could you help me please.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8081/WebService/services/SqlService.SqlServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint/";
    public static final String NAMESPACE = "http://services.com";
    public static final String SOAP_ACTION= "http://services.com/locationData";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "locationData";

    String str = null;
    TextView t;
    String longitude;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);



        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("message","Hello");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SoapPrimitive result;
        try {
            result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String strRes = result.toString();
            String resultArr[] = strRes.split("&");
            longitude = resultArr[0];
            t.setText(resultArr[0]);
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    public void sendLocation(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MappingActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("longitude",longitude);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.abc.MainActivity" 
    android:background="@drawable/background1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:onClick="sendLocation"
        android:text="Refresh Location"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.abc.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.abc.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="map_api_key" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >



            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MappingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mapping" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MappingActivity:

```
public class MappingActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap googleHarita;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        //String longitude = getIntent().getExtras().getString("longitude");
        //Float f = Float.parseFloat(longitude);

        if (googleHarita == null) {
            googleHarita = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.haritafragment))
                    .getMap();
            if (googleHarita != null) {

                LatLng istanbulKoordinat = new LatLng(0,29.004065);
                googleHarita.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(istanbulKoordinat).title("Kız Kulesi"));
                googleHarita.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(istanbulKoordinat, 13));    


        }
    }
}
```

}

map.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/haritafragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Web Service:

```
public String insertData(String longitude,String latitude,String time){

            try{

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con =  (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/places","root","");
                PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into location (COLUMN_LONGITUDE,COLUMN_LATITUDE,COLUMN_TIME)  values ('"+longitude+"','"+latitude+"','"+time+"')");


                int result=statement.executeUpdate();
                con.close();
            }catch(Exception exc){

                System.out.println(exc);

            }


            return time;

        }


    public String locationData(){

        String locationInfo="";

            try{

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con =  (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/places","root","");
                PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("select * from location");

                ResultSet result=statement.executeQuery();

                while(result.next()){

                    locationInfo=locationInfo+result.getString("COLUMN_LONGITUDE")+"&" +result.getString("COLUMN_LATITUDE")+ "&" +result.getString("COLUMN_TIME");

                }


            }catch(Exception exc){

                System.out.println(exc);

            }
            return locationInfo;

        }
```

logcat:

[errors in logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YtTE.png)

Comment: You must declare `MappingActivity.class` in your `Manifest file`

Comment: Yes I declared. I'm sharing manifest file.

Comment: Share your MappingActivity.class

Comment: The error points to what you are doing in `sendLocation` function where you try to start the `MappingActivity` - so please do show us the code in your `MappingActivity` - we need to examine this - for instance, that it does indeed exists, and extends `Activity`, etc..

Comment: sendLocation method is sending location informations web service . I'm sharing web service methods. I created in Eclipse EE this service.

Answer (score 0):

You are extending `FragmentActivity` in your MappingActivity instead an `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity` replace by it and will work.

Comment: I declared MappingActivity. But problem didn't solve.

Comment: Are you still with this problem?